# Expose legacy revealing module pattern methods and variables using Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to hotwire webpack to use some legacy code but this arrangement:

**slidesystem.js:**

```
export var slideSystem = (function () {

    var position = 0;

    function init() {
        alert('winner!');
    } // init

})();
```

**app.js**

```
import {slideSystem} from './slidesystem';

slideSystem.init();
alert(slideSystem.position);
```

Isn't working as expected... Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it using the demo above:

**slidesystem.js**

```
const slideSystem = (function () {

    'use strict';

    var position = 0;

    function init() {
        alert('winner!');
    } // init

    return {
        init: init,
        pos: pos
    };

})();
export default slideSystem;
```

**app.js**

```
import {slideSystem} from './slidesystem';

slideSystem.init();
alert(slideSystem.position);
```